# Use camera to analyze homogeneity

Tags: android, image-manipulation

We are working with some screens whose in the production process change their state from a transparent state to a colored state. This colored state is achieved to block light transmittance.

In this process where the screen gets tinted, this tint must be applied homogeneously. This is a very important point of the process.

To check this homogeneity, I've been asked to develop a mobile app (Android) in which using the camera I could check if the tint is applied homogeneously.

I'm an android programmer so the knowledge about android is not a problem. But I've never worked with images this way so I ignore if such a thing like this could be done.

My first idea is to develop an app which using the camera takes a photo, this is the easy part. After this, I should process the image some way that I could identify non homogeneous parts, maybe convert the image to grey scales and check for clearer or darker tones.

I'm not asking about how should I programm that, as this is just a first idea on how could I achieve this, what I'm asking help for is to know how could I do that kind of image processing that could detect homogeneity.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)**

Comment: @gnat I've edited the post

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're being asked to develop this as an Android application.  If this is a real production facility, you probably want to use some kind of industrial solution.  I would suggest contacting someone from a machine vision company like [Cognex](http://www.cognex.com/products.aspx) and tell them about your application.  They might have an off-the-shelf product that does exactly what you want, or can be programmed to do what you want, and will be a lot easier to integrate into your automation equipment than some kind of Android device.

Now, on to your actual question, if I was attacking that problem, I would try executing a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram) function on it.  I'd look at many samples of "good" vs. "bad" product and what those histograms looked like, and see if there are some easy limits that could be setup to sort the good from the bad ones.

As with most machine vision applications, lighting is critical.  Don't believe you can just take a flash photo and have it be consistent.  You need to have very consistent lighting and you need to experiment with front, rear, and side lighting to see what brings out the most contrast of the characteristics you want to measure.  Also consider using color filters on the camera, or even going with an infrared or UV light and infrared/UV camera/filter to see if that makes it easier to detect the defects.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Well, the thing is that this check is important for us, but is not relevant for the final product, I mean, at this moment we check the homogeneity visually and this is enought to determine the correct homogeneity level, so is not necesary to spend lots of money on visual systems like these. Thus I was asked if I could do something like this as just an idea, so it's in my hands to determine if It can be done or not

Comment: @mas:Does your time not cost the company money? I have no idea how much a 3rd party product would cost, but even if it's a couple thousand dollars I would bet that it will be cheaper to buy than for you to build in many cases. Especially since you give the impression that you have zero image processing experience/knowledge.

Comment: @masmic_87 - "Well, the thing is that this check is important for us, but is not relevant for the final product..."  If you follow lean manufacturing principles, then anything not relevant to the final product should be removed from the process.  At any rate, it sounds like a make-work project for you.

Comment: Guys, yes, maybe my english doesn't let me explain well the situation. But this would be something internal, no relevant for the project, just for us, and why not, also for me for learning and practicing with image processing. And @Scott I don't wanted to say that isn't relevant in that way, of course that is relevant as the tint must be homogeneous, but is something that the human eye can check, and we don't have to provide an exact value with the product specs.